# How to increase font size in NeatBeans IDE?

Tags: ide, netbeans

I just bought a new monitor that's rather large and I am having a lot of trouble reading the text on my editor. I tried increasing the font size the usual way by going to

Tools >> Options >> Fonts & Colors >> Clicking the "..." button next to font >> and then choosing a large font size

This is the result: (click for full size)

[image]

As you can see the cursor becomes a lot larger but the font size remains the same. Does anyone know another way to effectively increase font size in NetBeans?

Answer (score 119):

you might also want to change your font size for other parts of the IDE (other than the code).

Just add the parameter `--fontsize <size>` (default size is 11) to the startup command.

You can put it into the command line when launching IDE. You can also put it into the `netbeans.conf` file, which is in the `/etc` subdirectory of NetBeans installation.

Just place it as a last parameter into the `netbeans_default_options` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for this!!! I'm trying out size 20 now and it is so much easier to see - might even go higher, despite the equivalent of lost monitor real estate. Note for others: _Don't_ do `--fontsize=20` like I did at first, or Netbeans says it doesn't recognize the option; you need a space like `--fontsize 20`.

Comment: This sets the font size of the menus which was what I nedded, thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm: It is two dashes and a space "--fontsize 20" even though all the other parameters in that line are one dash and an equals sign.

Comment: CONFIRMED - just tried it following the other parameters single-dash and equals, but nope that breaks startup for Win10 netbeans, and using double-dash space like --fontsize 12 did the trick and it opens up with fontsize 12 or whatever fontsize number you put there.  SO MUCH BETTER!

Comment: It works only for Files/Projects/Services/Navigator... not for menus and treeview of projects/files

Comment: Lubuntu: found this correctly under ~/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans.conf, NOT under invisible dir ~/.netbeans/8.1/ and not /etc/netbeans.conf  .  Menus + treeview work for me.

Comment: July 2019 and you just made my day. Apache Netbeans 11 still works as described. Linux Fedora 30.

Answer (score 93):

To increase the font size of netbeans 7.3.1 and 7.3 , you go from menu 
***Tools>>Options>>"Fonts & Colors"*** (is an inner menu in the dialog window of ***Options***)

At the ***"Syntax"*** tab ,every entry in the ***"Category:"*** list-box ,you will notice that the font has the value ***"Inherited"***.
If you find in the ***"Category"*** list-box the entry with the name "*Default*" and change the font value of that, you will affect the font size of your editor, because everything is inherited from "*Default*" entry .

Another method  is to increase temporary the font of the editor by a combination of keys.
To find what are the keys go to the ***"Options"*** dialog window by 
***Tools>> Options***
and then choose the "***Keymap***" menu entry
and then in the "Search" textbox type "zoom text" and it will show you what combinations of keys for zooming in /out.

for example mine is the combination of **"alt"** key + **mouse wheel up/down**

Comment: @Bor - It took me a while to get what you are saying. Yep this is correct. We have to roll mouse wheel while pressing the mouse wheel :). No need to press any other key such as ctrl or shift. Thanks & up-voted

Comment: On Xubuntu/Xfce desktop it's necessary to press the mouse wheel and roll because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+mouse wheel up/down causes the desktop to zoom in and out.

Comment: This is for the font in the SOURCE panel in Netbeans, not NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 38):

1st Way:

press down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and scroll up or down (mouse wheel)

2nd way:

press down mouse scroll(wheel) button and scroll up or down

Comment: Not sure if you are referring to a Mac shortcut, but simply Alt + scroll works for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Handy feature, but it only increases/decreases font size for the current file being edited and does not seem to be persisted

Answer (score 29):

At Windows in the file C:\Program Files\NetBeans x.x\etc\netbeans.conf

Add "--fontsize [size]" at the end of line netbeans_default_options:

```
netbeans_default_options=".... --fontsize 16"
```

Comment: I can confirm this works for the latest version of Netbeans (8.2) on a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Works fine on Net Beans 11.1 in Windows 10. Editing needs administration priviledges.

Comment: @Rob--please show the line that you have for *netbeans default options*, Here's mine and it doesn't change any font size anywhere because Netbeans won't even launch unless I erase "fontsize 16" " *netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true--fontsize 16"

Answer (score 16):

Check this image with **red arrow direction** 
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Tools >> Options >> Fonts & Colors >> Syntax tab. Select 'Default' from the *Category* list and click the `...` button like you said.

It's the *Default* you need to select first before changing the size.

Answer (score 10):

In `OS X`, Netbeans `8.0`

1. Use `Command + ,` to open the options
2. Select `Fonts & Colors` tab
3. Click the button in the Font section (button is next to the Font textbox)
4. Change the Font, style and size as needed

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The solutions here just increase editor font size. You can run netbeans with parameter `netbeans --fontsize 20` You can edit windows link like this for example. `"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin\netbeans64.exe" --fontsize 20`

Answer (score 9):

Alt + scroll wheel will increase / decrease the font size of the main code window

Answer (score 8):

press `alt` and scroll down or up to change the size

Answer (score 6):

I would upgrade to newer Netbeans 7.1 or wait few days/weeks for 7.2, it can be a bug in Netbeans 6.8.

I just add to previous two solutions, that you can increase size temporary with <kbd>ALT</kbd>(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>) + mouse wheel as in browser. (<kbd>ALT</kbd> in Netbeans 7.2, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in Netbeans 7.1)

Answer (score 5):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> then click on Font browse option. Now you will see a popup box. Here you can change Font:, Font Style: and Size:

I had tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools|options|keymap.
Search for 'zoom in text' and set your preferred key.
I've set alt+plus and alt+minus.

Answer (score 2):

When i modify the font size in `Tools-> Options->Fonts & Colors->Syntax`to 14, the Editor font change fine, but Netbeans doesn´t take any change in fontsize IDE (icons, menus, ...) until i Add the `--fontsize XX` option in the file **...\NetBeans x.x\etc\netbeans.conf** at the end of line `netbeans_default_options` AND set to **true** the already added option `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware`, But i had to increase the font size Editor to 24. Thats works for me.

Answer (score 2):

### You can create your own shortcut for **increase/Decrease** Netbeans **Fonts** size

> just goto `Tools > Options > Keymaps` than search `zoom`

click on three (`...`) dot and click `Edit`

> press `your_shortcut_keys` ( what ever shortcut you want to set)

Answer (score 1):

For full control of **ANY** (non simplest editor, non head of tree) ui elements I recomend use plugin [UI Editor for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55618/ui-editor)

[image: Settings in action]

Answer (score 0):

**To set fonts and colors for displaying help pages:**

1.From the main window, choose File > Open File.

2.In the Open dialog box, navigate to IDE-install-directoryide/docs/org/netbeans/modules/usersguide and open the file ide.css.

The ide.css file is the style sheet that describes how to present the fonts and colors in the help pages.

3.Edit ide.css to your preferences.

4.Choose File > Save.

5.Open the help viewer and verify your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Literally NONE of these worked for me.

I am using **NetBeans 11.1** on **Linux**. I found the solution by searching the Options menu. The issue was the **IDE Theme**- which has an "Override" font size.

1. Tools > Options > Appearance > *Darcula Look And Feel*
2. Uncheck *"Override Default fonts by [ Dialog 10 ]"*
3. (OR increase the override font to a bigger size)
4. Hit OK
5. Exit and restart NetBeans!

Your environment preferences should be saved for future NetBeans sessions!

[image: Options Window]

Answer (score 0):

For Mac,
1.click on NetBeans then go to Preference or Just press (command and ,)
2.choose Font and colors
3. from the font tab increase the size and press ok.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?