# How to change NetBeans Font Size

Tags: netbeans, font-size

I am in trouble because font size of the Project window, File window and Service window is small.

How can I change to larger size fonts?

I do not hope that font size in other parts will be changed. E.g. tool menu font size.

I am using:

- Windows 7
- NetBeans 7.2.1

Comment: never used netbeans but doesn't some very common ctrl+mouse scroll do the trick ?

Comment: @Cimbali - Close, uses the not as common alt+mouse scroll.

Comment: @Cimbali--Thanks, that works fine. But I think OP (and I definitely) want to make some *permanent* IDE change that will NOT require `Alt+mouse_scroll` to make the font size acceptable every time the adjusted file window is closed and reopened, whether by `Ctrl+w` or exiting and reopening Netbeans **8.2**. *My* hope is that there's some way to make ALL characters in every window in the IDE display in the same font size.

Answer (score 38):

Edit the [netbeans.conf](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf) file (located in the /etc folder of your NetBeans installation), look for the line that starts with "netbeans_default_options=". Edit the fontsize parameter if present. If not, add something like "--fontsize 11" (without the quote) at the end of the line.

[Source](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize)

Comment: Thank you . I've read.

I had hoped to change the font size of the three windows ( Project window, Files window, and Service window).

The menu, tabs and others of NetBeans become huge font size  when using the "--fontsize" option.

I would want that it does not allow you to specify the font size individually.
I'm in trouble because presbyopia.

Comment: Unsure then sorry. I don't think there would be a way to change individual window's font sizes but have a look in Tools | Options | Fonts & Colors (or Tools | Options | Editing | Editor Settings in older versions).

Answer (score 34):

`Alt` + `scroll wheel` will increase / decrease the font size of the main code window

Comment: same for netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP explicitly asked about the Project, Service and File window. Alt + scroll wheel only works for the code window.

Comment: The title of the question picks up all ambiguity of what people are looking for, this may help. But true, it doesn't.

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the question exactly as asked, the question as asked is very narrow. One answer tells how to do it for the code and doesn't answer it fully, another answer shows how to do it for everything but OP doesn't want everything. The question is akin to "How do I attach a widget to a sprocket... but in a specific way that only works on Tuesdays between 8-9pm and only while I'm waving my left hand."

Answer (score 6):

For Linux: http://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/fix-netbeans-big-fonts-on-ubuntu.html

That post recommends adding

```
--laf Nimbus -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

It certainly works on Ubuntu 12.04.  I don't know if the same settings will work for Windows7 (but they could because they are Java settings, not OS settings).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

[image]

Size of font can be set via settings

Comment: I'm in doubt you got the question properly

Answer (score 1):

I have a NetBeans plugin called 'UI-Editor' that you can use to customize virtually all Swing Settings (including Font types, sizes, and colors). Go to Tools->Plugins and search for UI-Editor. Or go here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55618/?show=true

Answer (score 1):

Go to,

*Tools -> Options -> Appearance*

Check the box which says ***'Override default fonts by'***. Choose the Font Size. This should change the font of Project Window. Doesn't significantly affect the overall font.

Note : Im using Netbeans 8.2

Comment: How come I, using Nerbeans 8.2, don't see `Override defaults fonts by` when I follow `Tools, Options, Appearance`?

Comment: Check under the **Dracula Look and Feel tab**. Im using Dracula look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

So you are just trying to change the font size in netbeans? You can click on tools>options at the top and then click on the "Fonts and Colors" tab. There you can also change the color of the font.
Also, you can use Eclipse which is a little simpler than netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bin directory where Netbeans is installed. Generally the defualt is : `C:\Program Files\NetBeans <version>\bin`. Now through Command Prompt start netbeans by: `netbeans --fontsize <fontsize> --console suppress`. By using `--console suppress` you can close the cmd window, without the Netbeans window getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

My overall NetBeans (8.0) window and fonts was annoyingly and unpleasantly small so I found that Options/Appearance/Look and Feel - Windows Classic was the only one that could be used on a Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

A couple fellas (Muzaffar and GucciDiet) beat me to it on this question- but hope this helps someone :)

Below is my solution from 2 other similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692939/4739826) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65693001/4739826)

> Literally NONE of these worked for me.
>
> I am using **NetBeans 11.1** on **Linux**. I found the solution by
> searching the Options menu. The issue was the **IDE Theme**- which has
> an "Override" font size.
>
> 1. Tools > Options > Appearance > *Darcula Look And Feel*
> 2. Uncheck *"Override Default fonts by [ Dialog 10 ]"*
> 3. (OR increase the override font to a bigger size)
> 4. Hit OK
> 5. Exit and restart NetBeans!
>
> Your environment preferences should be saved for future NetBeans
> sessions!
>
> [image: Options Window]

Answer (score -3):

How about using a screen magnifier?

on Windows 7, [Sysinternals ZoomIt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/zoomit.aspx) works fine.

Nearly every Linux desktop has one as well.