# Increase the font size of output and menus in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I am using the latest version of NetBeans and I need to increase the font size of output and menus(Not the code part). I tried:

```
netbeans_default_options=".... --fontsize 16"
```

But the IDE doesn't startup when I add this to `netbeans.conf`. Please help me or I would go blind :D

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On Windows 10 editing `netbeans.conf` (appending the `--fontsize 16` to `netbeans_default_options`) normally should work (at least, it works for me with the latest NetBeans). Another solution is to start `netbeans.exe` with `--fontsize 16` option. For instance, having a shortcut to NetBeans on a desktop, you can modify it in the following fashion: right-click on the shortcut, click `Properties`, select `Shortcut`, append to the `target` line `--fontsize 16`.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\bin\netbeans64.exe" --fontsize 16

Comment: It worked. but putting --fontsize size option in netbeans file is not working. I don't understand why?. This question is a proof others are facing the same issue. But why?

Comment: Where is netbeans.conf?

Comment: @DamnVegetables, on Windows it's usually located here: `C:\Program Files\NetBeans\etc\netbeans.conf`

Comment: Changing netbeans.conf worked for me on Win10, NetBeans12

Comment: This answer is still relevant in 2024. The instructions from the source are here. https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/working_nbeans.htm#A1152090

Answer (score 2):

Go to the bin directory where Netbeans is installed. Generally the defualt is : `C:\Program Files\NetBeans <version>\bin`. Now through Command Prompt start netbeans by: `netbeans --fontsize 14 --console suppress`. By using `--console suppress` you can close the cmd window, without affecting the netbeans window.

Answer (score 2):

setting -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -> false, worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

NetBeans Menu :

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin>netbeans --fontsize 20
```

NetBeans Project folder/file navigation:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin>netbeans --laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel --fontsize 20
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions work for Menu and Project Tab. For output window, you can just press Ctrl + Up or right click in the area and select Larger (or smaller) Font.

Answer (score 0):

Install, register and set as default appropriate JDK (Tools -> Options -> Java -> Java Shell). For example: NetBeans 11.x - JDK 11.
Than use --fontsize.

Comment: This one continues to be the main method to use in 2024. https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/working_nbeans.htm#A1152090

Answer (score -1):

Literally NONE of any posted solution worked for me.

Below is my solution from another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692939/4739826)

> I am using **NetBeans 11.1** on **Linux**. I found the solution by
> searching the Options menu. The issue was the **IDE Theme**- which has
> an "Override" font size.
>
> 1. Tools > Options > Appearance > *Darcula Look And Feel*
> 2. Uncheck *"Override Default fonts by [ Dialog 10 ]"*
> 3. (OR increase the override font to a bigger size)
> 4. Hit OK
> 5. Exit and restart NetBeans!
>
> Your environment preferences should be saved for future NetBeans
> sessions!
>
> [image: Options Window]

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and NetBeans 12. I don't have it

Answer (score -1):

If you're on Windows then go to TOOLS > OPTIONS > MISCELLANEOUS > OUTPUT Click on font: to change font size

Comment: No, this is for output window, if you are missing it, you can activate it in menu->windows->output