# Trouble with Increase the font size of output and menus in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have tried to  increase the font size of my menu by using netbeans configuration file as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218584/8631622)

But it not working.
I have edited my netbeans.conf file.

**My netbeans.conf**

C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.1\netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf

```
     netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m  -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions 
   --fontsize 30 "
```

I used another way to change font size of GUI mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893220/8631622). And it worked.
But I don't understand why is the solution number one is not working.

**Details:**

Netbeans version: 12.1

Operating system: Windows 10

Architecture: 64 bit

**P.S.** The fact that this second question exits it means that lot of other people are facing the same issue.