# How to change the font size of contents in netbeans navigator window

Tags: netbeans-7, font-size

I want to change the font size of netbeans navigator window. I can change the font of editor window using Tools\Options\Fonts & Colors. But it is reflected only in the editor and not in other windows like Projects, Navigator, Output, Debug.

How to change this font this everywhere in Netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 3):

There is another method you can use for this.

1. Create a shortcut for the ide on the desktop.
2. Open the properties pane and in the target option where it is mentioned:
   "C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\bin\netbeans64.exe" just add `--fontsize 18` to the end.

So, it is going to look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.3\netbeans\bin\netbeans64.exe" --fontsize 18
```

Apply the changes and restart the IDE. The new font size will be applied.

[image: Screenshot]

**This goes for all kinds of Netbeans IDE no matter what the Version**

Comment: a simple life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You should find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218584/7793045).

> you might also want to change your font size for other parts of the IDE (other than the code).
>
> Just add the parameter --fontsize  (default size is 11) to the startup command.
>
> You can put it into the command line when launching IDE. You can also put it into the netbeans.conf file, which is in the /etc subdirectory of NetBeans installation.
>
> Just place it as a last parameter into the netbeans_default_options parameter.

Comment: If someone else has already answered the question it is normal to add a comment which links to that answer. You should not create your own answer that does nothing but link to the other post and copy from it.

Answer (score 0):

Output and Debug font size you will find from **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous** 
from the list select **Output** and change the font Size. Do the same thing for Terminal to solve the problem for Debugging.
Hope it helps you.