# Does anyone know how to zoom in on NetBeans syntax?

Tags: netbeans

I want to enlarge the code I've written in NetBeans so it's easier to read. I can enlarge the output by using ctrl and '+', but it doesn't work on the code. Does anyone know how to do this?  I really don't understand how to do this I have tried a multitude of things including using the magnifier but it just doesnt seem to work as well as I've hoped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase font size in NeatBeans IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181544/how-to-increase-font-size-in-neatbeans-ide)

Answer (score 1):

Just hold down the **ALT** key while scrolling the mouse wheel to increase/decrease the font size for code files.

You can view those shortcut settings as follows:

- Select **Tools -> Options** then click the **Keymap** icon
- Enter **zoom** in the **Search** field.

[image: Keymap zoom]

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG148) explains how you can assign different shortcuts to zoom in/out.