# how to change the font size of the tool bar in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, setting

the font size of  netbeans is very small I can't see the font and icons in the tool bar. how can i fix this problem?

my os is windows 10

Comment: see this:<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181544/how-to-increase-font-size-in-neatbeans-ide <br>
This has already been answered! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase font size in NeatBeans IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181544/how-to-increase-font-size-in-neatbeans-ide)