# Netbeans: how do I set the font size in the windows-labels

Tags: netbeans

The Netbeans IDE on my Windows 10 desktop has text, labeling all of its tabs and windows, that is so small that I cannot read it. How do I fix this?

Does anybody know of an *active* Netbeans Forum? A forum where I can post questions about the mechanics of Netbeans IDE as a standalone program? I know how to use it pretty well, but I now have second level questions that I have spent hours looking for answers to.

Comment: As NetBeans is an Apache project now, you will need to subscribe and post questions to the [mailing list](http://netbeans.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html)

Comment: Did you try `--fontsize 24` or something e.g. on the command line or by editing  `netbeans.conf`? (See e.g. [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-users/202003.mbox/%3cCALkRQxe1as6d1VB08_HkqGGkMeYQU0KpRKXrQoMR-_bhCry7MA@mail.gmail.com%3e)) Which Java version are you using? In general for HighDPI environments you should be using Java 11 or later (to **run** NetBeans)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase font size in NeatBeans IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181544/how-to-increase-font-size-in-neatbeans-ide)