# how to increase text font on NetBeans (classpath text, properties text)

Tags: java, file, text, netbeans, fonts

I need help enlarging the font of the text I marked.

[**Image and marked text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjA7D.png)

Comment: Not sure if, when you increase the whole font size that text changes too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181544/how-to-increase-font-size-in-neatbeans-ide

Comment: When I change the whole font size , the marked text wont change

Comment: Please post code and problem instead image link.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem . just added --fontsize 20 to my conf. Thank you